# The continue button doesn't work when the game is paused

Tags: pygame, python-3.6

I have made a game where you have to dodge objects. You can also pause the game by pressing p. Once you pause the game you get an option if you want to continue or quit. For me, the quit button is working but the continue button isn't. Where it says define unpause() is where the code starts for the pause button.

```
import time
import random

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

red = (200,0,0)
orange = (255, 165, 0)
yellow = (255, 242, 0)
green = (0,200,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
indigo = (75, 0, 130)
violet = (238, 130, 238)
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)


bright_red = (255,0,0)
bright_green = (0,255,0)


car_width = 86

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Racing Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

carImg = pygame.image.load("download.png")
carImg = pygame.transform.scale(carImg,(100,160))

pause = False

def things_dodged(count):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render ("Dodged: "+str(count), True, black)
    gameDisplay.blit(text,(0,0))

def things(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, color, [thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh])

def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg, (x,y))

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()


def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",100)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()

    game_loop()

    time.sleep(2000)


def crash():
    message_display ("YOU CRASHED")

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action = None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    print(click)
    if x + w > mouse [0] > x and y + h > mouse [1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac, (x,y,w,h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            if action == "play":
                game_loop()

            elif action == "quit":
                pygame.quit()
                quit()


    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic, (x,y,w,h))

    smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText) 
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def quitgame():
    pygame.quit()
    quit

def unpause():
    global pause
    pause = False


def paused():
    while paused:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        largeText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",100)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("PAUSED", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)


        button ("Continue!",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,unpause)
        button ("Quit!",550,450,100,50,red,bright_red,"quit")





        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)




def game_intro():
    intro = True
    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        largeText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",100)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Racing Game", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)


        button ("GO!",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,"play")
        button ("QUIT!",550,450,100,50,red,bright_red,"quit")





        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)



def game_loop():
    global pause
    x = (display_width * 0.45)
    y = (display_height * 0.72)

    x_change = 0

    thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
    thing_starty = -600
    thing_speed = 7
    thing_width = 100
    thing_height = 100

    thingCount = 1

    dodged = 0


    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -5
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 5
                if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                    pause = True
                    paused() 

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0

        x += x_change

        gameDisplay.fill(white)


        things(thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height, black)
        thing_starty += thing_speed
        car (x,y)
        things_dodged(dodged)

        if x > display_width - car_width or x < -10:
            crash()


        if thing_starty > display_height:
            thing_starty = 0 - thing_height
            thing_startx = random.randrange(0,display_width)
            dodged += 1
            thing_speed += 1
            #thing_width += (dodged * 0.5)


        if y < thing_starty + thing_height:


            if x > thing_startx and x < thing_startx + thing_width or x + car_width > thing_startx and x + car_width < thing_startx + thing_width: 
                crash()

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(100)

game_intro()        
game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()

Please try to help. I am saying Thank You in advance for all your guy's help.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in `while paused:` in `def paused()`- it has to be `while pause:`

```
def paused():
    while pause: # <- pause instead of paused
```